# How do i setup sencha touch 2 on windows 7 properly. I am try but can't

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

There is on problem occur on my CMD. when i am try to setup Sencha touch 2.There is show this kind of error[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run the command at **sencha sdk** folder not **sencha-touch-2** as you can see in the warning

Beside that I'd suggest you upgrading to sencha touch version 2.1 since it has a lot of enhancements. To run command in this version you need to download [Sencha Cmd](http://www.sencha.com/products/sencha-cmd/download) since Sencha SDK tools has been deprecated in this version and here is the [guide](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-1/#!/guide/command) on how to use this Sencha Cmd.

Hope it helps :)

Comment: I thought you were posting the same link as me but you are more up to date ;) I need to reorganize my bookmarks.

Comment: Glad to hear that. Feel free to upvote my anser if you find it's useful:)

Comment: I did not find it too useful but I like to like (only on this site).

Answer (score 1):

Follow the following step by step -

step 1 - Download all the sencha related SDKs if you dont have from [here](http://www.sencha.com/products/touch/download/)

step 2 - extract "**sencha-touch-2.3.0-gpl.zip**" to your project directory. and install the SenchaCmd and sencha SDK tools on your machine.

step 3 - open you command prompt and type sencha and enter.
if you see the output like - **Sencha Cmd v4.0.1.45** the everything is OK. other wise may be its a problem with your installation.

step 4 - Now you have to create a blank sencha touch app - go to the command prompt and write the following command -

**C:\inetpub\wwwroot\touch-2.3.0>sencha -sdk "location path where you have extracted the SDK"  gen
erate app MyApp "Location path where you want to create the app"**
for example in my case this is like - "**C:\inetpub\wwwroot\touch-2.3.0>sencha -sdk "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\touch-2.3.0"  gen
erate app MyApp "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\ITK_2.0"**"

step 5 - host the app on your web server (I am using IIS 8 on my windows 8 machine) and hit the URL **"localhost/MyApp/"**.

thats all.

Happy Coding.

Answer (score 0):

It is a warning not an error. You can find more about the command line tool @ [here](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-1/#!/guide/command)